# An example of Cauchy's Local Integral Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to use the  local version of Cauchy's integral theorem to calculate the following integral:

\begin{align*}
\int_{|z| = 1} \frac{1}{z^2 + 2z}.
\end{align*}

The version of the theorem I'm using requires the integrand to be continuous on $\Delta$ and analytic on $\Delta \setminus \{z_0\}$, where $\Delta$ contains the trajectory of the contour.

Taking $z_0 = 0$, and $\Delta(0, \delta)$, where $\delta >  1$, to be any disk of radius greater than $1$ centered at $0$, the integrand, is analytic but not continuous on $\mathbb{C} \setminus \{ 0 \}$.

I'm not sure how to proceed. I'm suspect the value of the integral would be non-zero, as is the case with the function $1/z$. I'm hence tempted to evaluate the integral using the brute force method of evaluating contour integrals.

Am I missing out on something?

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* Write
$$
\frac{1}{z^2 + 2 z} = \frac{1}{2 z} - \frac{1}{2 z + 4}
$$
and do it by hand.

Comment: But still, the first fraction isn't continuous at $0$. But we can evaluate the integral by hand. So, it seems Cauchy's Theorem doesn't apply and the answer is non-zero, as I anticipated. Correct? Though, of course, partial decomposition gives a better way to evaluated the integral.

Comment: who says it has to be continuous at 0?

Comment: @Fightclub1995 Assuming I enclose the circle in a disk of radius greater than 1, the version of the theorem I'm using requires it to be continuous at all points of the disk, including zero, and analytic at the disk minus some fixed point, $z_0$.

Comment: it's 1/2z-1/(2z+4)

Comment: @蔡易翔, thanks for spotting this!

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the function as:

$$
\int_{|z| = 1} \frac{1}{z^2 + 2z}=\
\int_{|z| = 1} \frac{\frac{1}{z+2}}{z}$$

The function $$\frac{1}{z+2}$$ is analytic on the disk

Using [Cauchy's integral formula](http://27s_integral_formula): $$f(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(z)}{z-a}$$

$$\
\int_{|z| = 1} \frac{\frac{1}{z+2}}{z}=2\pi i \frac{1}{2}=\pi i$$